# Review audits should not tell you when successfully completing one

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

When you complete a review audit, you see a blue modal that informs you of successfully completing an audit.

I think this is a bad idea as it enables review abusers to spam a few clicks knowing that it is near impossible to get another audit immediately after another.

Failing review audits obviously should inform you of such so you may improve, completing one successfully serves no purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Audits are pretty weak.  They can't offer much more correction than saying that you went against what everyone else thought of this question, which isn't always accurate, given that we do have some false positives in the system.

They're also *super* obvious if you know what to look for in a question.

So maybe I disagree with your assessment that by somehow not telling someone that they passed an audit, we'll have fewer review abusers floating about.  One doesn't have a strong correlation to the other.